# Seaborn Scatter plot custom legend showing Single Label

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot

I used the below code to plot a scatter plot using seaborn. I need to change the labels text in legend. But when I add custom text for the legends, it's only showing one label. I need to have legend text as ['set', 'versi', 'vir']. The code is as below -

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

scatter = sns.scatterplot(x='sepal_length', y ='sepal_width', hue='species', data=iris, legend=False)
scatter.legend(labels = ['set', 'versi', 'vir'], loc='upper right')
plt.show(scatter)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn's sophisticated way of working can't always follow the rules needed for a standard legend (see e.g. [issue 2280](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2280)). Often, the legend is custom created. Currently, matplotlib doesn't provide simple functions to move (or alter) such a legend.

In seaborn 0.11.2, a function [`sns.move_legend(ax, ...)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html#seaborn.move_legend) ([info on github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/2643)) is added, which can move the legend and change some other properties (but not the labels).

So, you can first let `sns.scatterplot` create a legend, and then move it.

The labels in the legend come from the element names in the hue-column. To obtain different names, the most straightforward way is to temporarily rename them.

Here is some example code (note that `plt.show()` doesn't have an `ax` as parameter, but does have an optional `block=` parameter):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species',
                     data=iris.replace({'species': {'setosa': 'set', 'versicolor': 'versi', 'virginica': 'vir'}}))
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with moved and renamed legend]

Comment: Thanks. In version - 0.11.1, I changed the location using ax.legend(loc = 'upper right')